# Destructuring optional properties

Tags: javascript

I would like to create a function that takes one optional property called `verbose`, and if it's not specified it defaults to true. Here is an example:

```js
function Counter(n=0, {verbose=false}) {
    return function() {
        n++;
        if (verbose) console.log(n);
        return n;
    }
}
let c1 = Counter(0, {verbose: true});
c1(), c1(), c1();
```

Everything works fine. However, as soon as I call it without the object param, I get an error:

```js
function Counter(n=0, {verbose=false}) {
    return function() {
        n++;
        if (verbose) console.log(n);
        return n;
    }
}
let c1 = Counter(0);
// TypeError: Cannot read property 'verbose' of undefined
```

Why does this occur, as I thought the whole point of having an object that can be destructured in the argument list is the suggested way to have a bunch of optional arguments that can be called. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The problem is that if you don't supply *any* object, it's not defaulting the second parameter to an object.

Comment: @VLAZ so the correct way to call it would be with an empty object? Such as: `let c1 = Counter(0, {});` ? Or what would be the proper way to handle the above?

Comment: Does it need to be an object? Could the [default parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters) simply be `verbose=false`?

Comment: `function Counter(n=0, {verbose=false} = {})` you need a default parameter.

Comment: @jarmod This is probably a simplification and the real application will have multiple options in the object.

Comment: @VLAZ That's a better solution than mine, since it doesn't require repeating all the property names.

Comment: @AlexanderNied Why did you delete your answer? It's the best solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't put the default in the destructuring pattern, put it in a default value that's assigned to the whole object.

```js
function Counter(n=0, {verbose} = {verbose: false}) {
    console.log(verbose);
    return function() {
        n++;
        if (verbose) console.log(n);
        return n;
    }
}
let c1 = Counter(0);
let c2 = Counter(0, {verbose: true});
```

Comment: Now it doesn't work if you call `Counter(0, {})`. You *should* put the default in the destructuring pattern.

Comment: Somone else posted a solution like that, but for some reason they deleted it.